# Wordpress: Passing images from one form to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form where users can upload images as well as other data. How can I pass the uploaded images to another form upon pressing the submit button? I can pass text input values successfully already- passing the images is the only issue. This is the first form:

```
<form class="usp-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.aeroe.com/gate/" data-validate="parsley" data-persist="garlic" novalidate>

<input name="ttitle" type="text" value="" data-required="true" required="required" maxlength="99" placeholder="" class="usp-input usp-input-title" />

<input name="usp-files" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />

<input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">

</form>
```

This is the second form (I have tried to echo $_POST the filename which seems to only work for the text input):

```
<form class="usp-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" http://www.aeroe.com/submit/" data-validate="parsley" data-persist="garlic" novalidate>

<input name="ttitle" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['ttitle']; ?>" data-required="true" required="required" maxlength="99" placeholder="" class="usp-input usp-input-title" />

<input name="usp-files[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['usp-files']; ?>" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />

<input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">

</form>
```

If anyone would be able to help  me come up with a solution to this I'd be very appreciative.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the second form put this between the form tags:

```
foreach ($_FILES["usp-files"] as $file) {
    echo '<input name="usp-files[]" value="'.$file["usp-files"]["tmp_name"].'" type="hidden"  />';
}
```

Then in the index file of http://www.aeroe.com/submit/ you can get the files and do whatever you want with them like this:

```
foreach ($_POST["usp_files"] as $file) {
    //get the location of the file
    $fileslocation= tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $file);

    //move the file to somewhere else
    move_uploaded_file($file, $destination);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I was looking more to set the 'value' of the file input,  as I don't want to print the images on the second form. This is because eventually I will want to forward these images to a third form. I tried to do this: <input value="<?php print_r($_FILES['usp-files']); ?>" name="usp-files[]" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />   Thanks again.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I'm afraid this hasn't worked! This method results in the following code appearing in the front end: foreach ($_FILES["usp-files"] as $file) { echo ''; }

Comment: you mentioned inserting the code in the index file of http://www.aeroe.com/submit/. I'm using wordpress, so is the index file simply the file named index.php ? This is the only index file I could find in the whole theme directory, so I'm assuming this index.php is shared by all of the pages?

Comment: @p.luck I thought  the page you want to post is not wordpress. In this case, you can add the codes in your functions.php. I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: okay, so the first snippet of code goes within the second form tags, and the last snippet goes in to functions.php?

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to get the file with the help of Files attributes.

you have to use this code

```
$_FILES['usp-files']['name'] // for file name
$_FILES['usp-files']['tmp_name'] // for temporary file name
```

Instead of your this code

```
$_POST['usp-files']
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This works fine, but I need to be able to set it as the file input value like this: <input value="<?php echo $_FILES['usp-filess']['name']; ?>" name="usp-files[]" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false"  />    This method doesn't seem to work when I do this however.